# What does a red text-background mean in GitHub comparison view?

Tags: github, diff

I created a pull request and was browsing through, the differences are shown with light red/green line-brackgrounds, but some text is bolded with a red text background...

Update: Image changed to show file with some highlighted comments and some not.
[image: GitHub comparison view showing text with red background]

What does this mean?

Comment: A syntax error. [JSON](http://json.org/) doesn't support comments.

Comment: Other comments in the same file are not highlighted, so I don't think that's it (unless it doesn't work properly?)

Comment: As soon as the document is invalid, it becomes harder for a parser to make sense of it, I'm with @JonathanLonowski's reply. Can you update the question to show the comments that are not red?

Comment: @jhabbott It's at least an error being reported by the syntax highlighter, noting unrecognized syntax. It's possible the project can still read the file using a less-strict or modified parser. However, standard-compliant parsers will throw an error -- `SyntaxError: Unexpected token /`.

Comment: Updated image. Regarding parsing it, the comments are stripped and JSON validated with a strict parser during build anyway. For the purposes of this question, I only want to know what GitHub is trying to show by the red highlights - if it is invalid syntax then it's not very consistent.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The red background-color is definitely being caused by the error-highlighting feature of GitHub's text editor/viewer. You can find the same behaviour occurring to an intended block comment in [another JSON file](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-strip-json-comments/blob/master/test/fixture/original.json) on GitHub:

[image: Screenshot of syntax error highlighting in GitHub]

As for your comment about some illegal characters not being highlighted: I also found that certain JSON errors aren't caught by GitHub's syntax processor. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/70fc32386ec6d33ab8e7) as an example:

[image: Example of uncaught errors in syntax highlighting]

In this case, the text outside of the outermost object isn't being highlighted. Whatever reason there is for this may be the same reason that errors aren't being highlighted for you.

You can test it out for yourself by copy-pasting your code into a [new Gist](https://gist.github.com). Note that the ACE Editor has its own highlighting feature that can highlight code as you type, but its processing rules seem to be a bit different from that of GitHub's code viewer.

Comment: Is there a way to tell github that this is not wrong / on purpose / another syntax? I upload a lot of *rc files that get highlighted quite a lot. Not a big deal, but I'd prefer it not to be highlighted.

Comment: Located this issue in GitHub - one comment states that the error-highlighting it doesn't happen if you use the `*.jsx` extension instead of `*.js`.
https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/3044

Answer (score 5):

This is issue makes code review process hard especially for the React(JSX) projects. Almost all the files with JSX showed the red lines.

I fixed it by copy pasting

```
var errorLine = document.getElementsByClassName("pl-ii");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < errorLine.length; i++) {
    errorLine[i].style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    errorLine[i].style.color = "#24292e";
}
```

on my console

Comment: This is because you're using a `.js` extension, this should not happen if you use the `.jsx` extension.

Comment: thanks for the workaround, working with `.cshtml` is a real PITA