# How to fix/ignore syntax error in github

Tags: github, syntax

I uploaded some code to github and there is nothing wrong with the code itself, but I get some kind of syntax error...

[image]

I do not believe there is anything wrong with my code as my text editor does not throw an error. Is this being caused by the `'` in `Don't`?

How can I get rid of this highlighting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30669730/6309)

> The red background-color is definitely being caused by the error-highlighting feature of GitHub's text editor/viewe

That means the syntax highlighting engine [Rouge](https://github.com/jneen/rouge) and [Pygment](http://pygments.org/) (mentioned in [GitHub pages for instance](https://help.github.com/articles/using-syntax-highlighting-on-github-pages/)) has its lexer not intepreting correctly this sequence of characters.

For xml, you can try and add the faulty character (`'` or `#`) in an xml comment on the same line to see if that alleviate the problem

```
<a... href='#'>Register</a> <!-- ' -->
or
<a... href='#'>Register</a> <!-- # -->
```