# Is There Any Way to Disable Error Highlighting in Github?

Tags: github, github-linguist

Github highlights the second `%` in this line as an error:

```
fscanf(fp, "%d%*[^\n]\n", &ints[i]);
```

However, the code compiles perfectly and the removing the 'error' will cause the program to function incorrectly.
Is there any way to either disable this error highlighting or make Github recognize it as correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: [pchaigno](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6884590/pchaigno) points out [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41604413/is-there-any-way-to-disable-error-highlighting-in-github/41605766#comment78303347_41605766) the section [linguist#Overrides](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides), where you can use for instance `.gitattributes`:

> Add a `.gitattributes` file to your project and use standard git-style path matchers for the files you want to override to set linguist-documentation, `linguist-language`, `linguist-vendored`, and `linguist-generated`.   `.gitattributes` will be used to determine language statistics and will be used to syntax highlight files. You can also manually set syntax highlighting using Vim or Emacs modelines.

```
$ cat .gitattributes
*.rb linguist-language=Java
```

---

Original Answer Jan. 2017

Since you cannot easily remove the GitHub highlight, you can try and use a similar workaround I suggested in "[How to fix/ignore syntax error in github](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41341604/6309)"

Try and add on the same line a comment with a '`%`' in it, in order for the lexer (used by the syntax highlighting engine [Rouge](https://github.com/jneen/rouge) and [Pygment](http://pygments.org/)) to not propagate the "error" to all subsequent lines.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this method does not appear to change it for me.

Comment: @parallel_resistance it usually requires a few attempts before finding the right character or sequence which would close the "error" detected by the lexer.

Comment: Okay, I already tried `//%` and `//%d`, so I'll mess around with it more tomorrow.

Comment: @VonC This answer would need to be updated; it is now possible to disable syntax highlighting thanks to [Linguist overrides](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides).

Comment: @pchaigno Thank you . I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

To complete VonC's answer, if you think the highlighting is incorrect, you can actually file a bug report or even fix it; All grammars github.com uses are open source!

**How to find the grammar?** To find the grammar used for syntax highlighting in your case, you can visit [this page on the Linguist project](https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/vendor). In front of each language (looks like C in your case), you'll find the repository where the grammar for that language lives (for C, [github.com/textmate/c.tmbundle](https://github.com/textmate/c.tmbundle)). You can open an issue there with your failing test case, or even better, try and fix it yourself.