# git diff: What is red text background in terminal output?

Tags: git, diff

Here's the output of my terminal when I run a git diff and scroll down with down arrow. From what I can assume and a couple articles I found, it looks like the red highlighting represents a syntax error?  Here's one source I found with good answers. [What does a red text-background mean in GitHub comparison view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667675/what-does-a-red-text-background-mean-in-github-comparison-view)
[image: git diff terminal zsh output with red text background]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The highlighted spaces indicate what git considers a whitespace error. `git diff`'s `--check` option has some documentation on it:

```
       --check
           <...>
           By default, trailing whitespaces (including lines that consist solely of
           whitespaces) and a space character that is immediately followed by a tab
           character inside the initial indent of the line are considered
           whitespace errors.
           <...>
```

You can get the reason (which, in your case, will be "trailing whitespace") with `git diff --check`:

```
$ git diff --check
my_file:107: trailing whitespace.
+end
```

Answer (score 2):

`git diff` can flag "whitespace errors".  A whitespace error is what you pick, out of Git's set of possible configurations: use the `core.whitespace` configuration knob to set this.  The default, as described in [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config), is:

```
blank-at-eol,space-before-tab,blank-at-eof
```

Having detected a whitespace error, Git will flag this with the color setting, which defaults to this background-red that you see.

These are *all* configurable: what counts as a "whitespace error", whether `git diff` should *look for* whitespace errors, and how `git diff` should *display* whitespace errors if found.  Search the documentation for the word "whitespace" to find these.  See also [Leonardo Dagnino's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71454407/1256452).